# Find single existing name

Tags: sql

I'm stuck with a homework about relational algebra and I'm getting nowhere. I got a database where different teachers are registered at different courses. What I should do is to find the teacher that is only registered to one single course.

Example of what the database looks like:

```
Course  |  TeacherName
--------+-----------------
Math    |  Peter
History |  Kyle
History |  Kyle
```

So in this example I should find Peter, but I'm all lost and don´t know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  TeacherName
FROM    YourTableName
GROUP BY TeacherName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

**[Example On SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96501/1)**